# Performance comparison of JDBC connection pools

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, connection-pooling

Does anyone have any information comparing performance characteristics of different ConnectionPool implementations?

Background: I have an application that runs db updates in background threads to a mysql instance on the same box. Using the Datasource com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource  would give us occasional SocketExceptions:
    com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

```
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Broken pipe

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
```

Increasing the mysql connection timeout increased the frequency of these errors.

These errors  have disappeared on switching to a different connection pool (com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource); however the performance may be worse and the memory profile is noticeably so (we get fewer, and much larger, GC's than the c3p0 pool).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever connection pool you use, you need to assume that the connection could be randomly closed at any moment and make your application deal with it.

In the case with a long-standing DB connection on a "trusted" network, what often happens is that the OS applies a time limit to how long connections can be open, or periodically runs some "connection cleanup" code. But the cause doesn't matter too much -- it's just part of networking life that you should assume the connection can be "pulled from under your feet", and deal with this scenario accordingly.

So given that, I really can't see the point of a connection pool framework that doesn't allow you to handle this case programmatically.

(Incidentally, this is another of my cases where I'm glad I just write my own connection pool code; no black boxes mysteriously eating memory, and no having to fish around to find the "magic parameter"...)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at some benchmark numbers up at http://jolbox.com - the site hosting BoneCP, a connection pool that is faster than both C3P0 and DBCP.

Comment: The link in your answer doesn't contain relevant information.

Comment: It's a link from 10+ years ago. BoneCP has been deprecated for a number of years by now. Look at HikariCP instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error pop up with mysql & c3p0 as well - I tried various things and eventually made it go away. I can't remember, but what might have solved it was the autoReconnect flag a la

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did find references to this, although it didn't solve my problem. +1

Comment: <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds --> try this - Since mysql is closing connections by timeout, this prob pings your db every once and a while to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp)? I don't know about c3po but DBCP can handle idle connections in different ways:

- It can remove idle connections from the pool
- It can run a query on idle connections after a certain period of inactivity

It can also test if a connection is valid just before giving it to the application, by running a query on it; if it gets an exception, it discards that connection and tries with another one (or creates a new one if it can). Way more robust.

Comment: Unless a lot has changed in DBCP since we stress tested it, judging by this http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/changes-report.html no, we found DBCP to significantly inferior in performance and handling terms. Have you looked into Proxool?

Comment: can you elaborate on that? I looked briefly at Proxool and it wasn't clear that it was up-to-date, but other than that I'm unfamiliar with it. Can you post more details about your experience as a complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

> *Broken pipe*

That roughly means that the other side has aborted/timedout/closed the connection. Aren't you keeping connections that long open? Ensure that your code is properly closing all JDBC resources (`Connection`, `Statement` and `ResultSet`) in the finally block.

> *Increasing the mysql connection timeout increased the frequency of these errors.*

Take care that this timeout doesn't exceed the DB's own timeout setting.